# module does not exist in the haste module map

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new here, I hope I enter all the information needed.

When trying to do some webscraping in my app, I got errors

```
module...does not exist in the haste module map" with 'events' and 'stream'.
```

I researched my issue, and tried the directions at: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 except for the watchman step, since I am on Windows.
Unfortunately, the same error keeps popping up, just with different modules. This time its babel that's complaining.

What should I do?

I also tried making a new react-native-init project and just git cloning my src code. Still get a similar error.

```
{
  "name": "Work",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "events": "^3.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "htmlparser2": "^3.9.2",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.21.0",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.11.17",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.13.0",
    "react-twitter-embedded-timeline": "^0.5.0",
    "react-twitter-widgets": "^1.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Copied from node cmd screen.
[image: CMD]

Comment: FYI there is a watchman binary for windows. It works surprisingly well

Comment: It is worth downloading watchman just to be able to follow some steps?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @MoshFeu I did... unfortunately I forget how. I think I rebuilt

Comment: Thanks! I resolved it too. The problem was that `events` is part of node internal modules which not exist in `v8` so I installed this module separately and it work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with my react-native app.
resetting the node cache solved the issue for me :

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

I hope it helps